# Webpage should not refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, refresh

I need a webpage should not refresh while clicking, but it should pass id of that link.

```
<?php echo "<a href='http://localhost/ss/index.php?albumid={$id}#photo'><img src=http://localhost/ss/admin/html/".$p['path']." class='img-responsive' alt='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.bs-example-modal-lg1'></a>";

<?php if(isset($_GET['albumid'])) $mid = $_GET['albumid']; ?>
```

I have tried ajax, but it is not working.
Is it possible? Can u please help me?

Comment: i tried with ajax jquery. but the issue is undefined index: albumid

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pass id, and then make a ajax call so page refresh can be avoided.

Following is the code, how you can pass the id and make use of jQuery for ajax call

`<div id='link1'><a href='yourfilename.php?id=1'>abc</a></div>`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#link1").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url:"abc.php",success:function(result){
      //Code after the success of ajax call
    }});
  });
});
</script>
```

It will surely help you dear